# Steps to deploy file.war in ElasticBeansTalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to deploy a file.war in my Elastic Beanstalk Account via eclipse java code..while creating  an application  with CreateApplicationRequest i have to specify the location of the source file..My question is ,should i create first an Simple storage Bucket and i add my war file  into it, then call it with

```
    String S3Bucket="amazonaws.com";
     String S3Key="SampleServlet.war";

     S3Location s=new S3Location(S3Bucket,S3Key);

    CreateApplicationVersionRequest v=new CreateApplicationVersionRequest(appName,description);
        v.setVersionLabel(versionLabel);
            v.setSourceBundle(s);

    eb.createApplicationVersion(v);
```

?? Can you help me Please ..

Answer (score 0):

I vote against using the eclipse plugin. I found it too cumbersome and unreliable. Switch to [eb cli v3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-eb.html) and follow the documentation. Basically you will need to work with git rather than provide a file, which is much easier.

Comment: Unfortunally , i have to work with eclipse because i'm trying to develop a REST elasticbeanstalk interface client that allows for user to create and deploy application from the local interface after authentication with credentials values,so i cannot use eb cli..

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution, i should create a bucket into S3 service and upload the file to store,then i call it in elastic beanstalk.

```
             AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
         s3client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
         try {
         if(!(s3client.doesBucketExist(bucketName)))
         {

         s3client.createBucket(new CreateBucketRequest(bucketName));
         }
         String key="file.war";

         File file=new File("file.war");

         PutObjectRequest ob=new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,key,file);
        PutObjectResult rs=s3client.putObject(ob);


      String S3Bucket=b.getName();
      String S3Key="file.war";

    S3Location s=new S3Location(S3Bucket,S3Key);

     CreateApplicationVersionRequest v=new CreateApplicationVersionRequest(appName,description);
    v.setVersionLabel(versionLabel);
        v.setSourceBundle(s);

           eb.createApplicationVersion(v);

            // eb is ElasticBeanstalk'Client
```

Then to deploy , just use updateEnvironment(appName,envName).